# How to force wcf service to serialize a class

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I am creating a WCF service and handling errors by throwing `WebFaultException<MyResultClass>`. (MyResultClass) is a class in my project:

```
[DataContract]
    public class MyResultClass
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
        public int Code;
        [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
        public string Description;
        public MyResultClass()
        {

        }

    }
```

The problem is that WCF service is not serializing this class.

Comment: Did you tried jus [DataMember] ? Try with properties
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all (as others have mentioned) you should use properties.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyResultClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Code { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { set; get; }
}
```

Furthermore, you need to specify the `FaultContract` in your interface. Otherwise the client cannot know what to expect. Since `WebFaultException` inherits from `FaultException` you don't need to specify it.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService:
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyResultClass))]
    void DoStuff();
}
```

And your implementaion:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var detail = new MyResultClass
        {
            Code = 400,
            Description = "foo"
        };
        throw new WebFaultException<MyResultClass>(detail, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

And your client:

```
try
{
    // Call your WCF service here...
}
catch (FaultException<MyResultClass> e)
{
    MyResultClass detail = e.Detail;
    // Do stuff with detail
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Some other error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

please change your class to this and try:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyResultClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Code { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { set; get; }

}
```